# Custom Token Response in Laravel Passport

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

The default response of Laravel Passport comes like this:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": djabjkdakadbakdkakjdbjkba
}
```

I need to add some custom response like:

```
{  
   "success":"true",
   "message":"Login Successful",
   "status":"200",
   "data":{
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 31536000,
      "access_token":"djabjkdakadbakdkakjdbjkba"
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me about this idea?

Comment: Did you search for "laravel custom responses" on the web? What about those resources does not apply to you? What have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

I have been banging my head for hours until I found the solution. This currently works for my version of Laravel 5.5.33:

1. Add a new route in your *api.php* file.

   ```
   Route::post('oauth/token', 'AccessTokenController@issueToken');
   ```
2. Create new file in YourProject/app/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\User;
   use Exception;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
   use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
   use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
   use Response;
   use \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController as 
   ATC;

   class AccessTokenController extends ATC
   {
       public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
       {
           try {
               //get username (default is :email)
               $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];

               //get user
               //change to 'email' if you want
               $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();

               //generate token
               $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);

               //convert response to json string
               $content = $tokenResponse->getContent();

               //convert json to array
               $data = json_decode($content, true);

               if(isset($data["error"]))
                   throw new OAuthServerException('The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials', 401);

               //add access token to user
               $user = collect($user);
               $user->put('access_token', $data['access_token']);
               //if you need to send out token_type, expires_in and refresh_token in the response body uncomment following lines
               // $user->put('token_type', $data['token_type']);
               // $user->put('expires_in', $data['expires_in']);
               // $user->put('refresh_token', $data['refresh_token']);

               return Response::json(array($user));
           }
           catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { // email not found
               //return error message
               return response(["message" => "User not found"], 500);
           }
           catch (OAuthServerException $e) { //password not correct..token not granted
               //return error message
               return response(["message" => "The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials"], 500);
           }
           catch (Exception $e) {
               ////return error message
               return response(["message" => "Internal server error"], 500);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Done! you can customize whatever you want over here, with whatever conditions you have. This was a lazy approach to not make your own PassportServiceProvider. Credits go to: **nauvalazhar** https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `getExtraParams` in `BearerTokenResponse` class.

```
    /**
     * Add custom fields to your Bearer Token response here, then override
     * AuthorizationServer::getResponseType() to pull in your version of
     * this class rather than the default.
     *
     * @param AccessTokenEntityInterface $accessToken
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getExtraParams(AccessTokenEntityInterface $accessToken)
    {
        return [];
    }
```

By overriding it your problem will be solved.