# dusterio/lumen-passport: Pass custom data in JWT Payload

Tags: jwt, laravel-passport, payload, passport-jwt

I am using [lumen-passport](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport) for authentication and authorization. When I decode the JWT token I get payload as below:

```
{
  "aud": "9420abb1-1470-4895-8666-a702b415cb59",
  "jti": "03b55ab9d73953207a7e568657a1f83a9c5dcc0162b43fe4816c6086d30d4002b9bd74604ba99ea6",
  "iat": 1635781614.447866,
  "nbf": 1635781614.447872,
  "exp": 1635783414.409659,
  "sub": "1b910fc7-54bc-44ef-885b-869b2a095c11",
  "scopes": []
}
```

`sub` is the user uuid. I want to pass custom data along with the `sub` as below.

```
{
  "aud": "9420abb1-1470-4895-8666-a702b415cb59",
  "jti": "03b55ab9d73953207a7e568657a1f83a9c5dcc0162b43fe4816c6086d30d4002b9bd74604ba99ea6",
  "iat": 1635781614.447866,
  "nbf": 1635781614.447872,
  "exp": 1635783414.409659,
  "sub": "1b910fc7-54bc-44ef-885b-869b2a095c11",
  "custom_data": "this is a custom data.",
  "scopes": []
}
```

How I can achieve this in [dusterio/lumen-passport](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport) or [laravel/passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport)?

I am generating token as below:

```
public function authenticateWithPassword(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        string $email,
        string $password,
        string $scope = ''
    ): Response {
        $newBody = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'username' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
            'scopes' => $scope,
        ];

        $newRequest = $request->withParsedBody($newBody);

        // We forward the request to Lumen's AccessTokenController since that does everything we want.
        return (App::make(AccessTokenController::class))->issueToken($newRequest);
    }
```

---

I tried different approaches:

- [Customising token response Laravel Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146964/customising-token-response-laravel-passport) (This is something I am not looking for)
- [How to add custom claims to laravel-passport Access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932881/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-laravel-passport-access-token) (This is something I am looking for but the solutions given doesn't work)
- [Custom Token Response in Laravel Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714988/custom-token-response-in-laravel-passport) (This is something I am not looking for)
- https://medium.com/geekculture/restrict-jwt-token-with-ip-address-using-laravel-77ce5ae3671a (The similar solution I am looking for lumen passport)